# No route matches [GET] "/accounts.json"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, subdomain, apartment-gem

I am attempting to provide a user with the ability to create a subdomain. When clicking Create Account, the system redirects from "accounts/new" to "accounts" and no subdomain is getting populated.

routes.rb

```
class SubdomainPresent
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present?
  end
end

class SubdomainBlank
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.blank?
  end
end

Saasapp::Application.routes.draw do

  constraints(SubdomainPresent) do
    root 'projects#index', as: :subdomain_root
    devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' } 
    resources :users, only: :index
    resources :projects, except: [:index, :show, :destroy]
  end

  constraints(SubdomainBlank) do
    root 'visitors#new'
    resources :accounts, only: [:new, :create]
  end
end
```

accounts_controller.rb

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :create]


  def new
    @account = Account.new
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    if @account.valid?
      Apartment::Database.create(@account.subdomain)
      Apartment::Database.switch(@account.subdomain)
      @account.save
      redirect_to new_user_session_url(subdomain: @account.subdomain)
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end
```

new.html.erb

```
 <%= simple_form_for @account do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :subdomain do %>
      <div class="input-group">
        <%= f.input_field :subdomain, class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="input-group-addon">.demo.dev</span>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: 'btn-primary' %>
  <% end %>
```

error in logs

```
Started GET "/accounts.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-08 21:56:08 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/accounts.json"):
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
resources :accounts, only: [:new, :create]
```

is telling Rails "only set up the `new` and `create` route for an account".

It basically says "do not set up an index route"

if you want an index route (ie that will show a list of all the accounts) then you need to update that line to eg:

```
resources :accounts, only: [:new, :create, :index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **:index** route to line:
  **resources :accounts, only: [:new, :create]**
In AccountsController **create index action** and handle
 **render json: YourObject**